# Drag and drop on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented drag and drop here. Try clicking on the ball and dragging it around.

http://joelin.org/p/mouse2.html

However, I used the html element as the one that catches mouse events. If I use the ball element to catch events instead, my mouse pointer quickly leaves the ball behind if the mouse pointer moves too fast.

I would like the listener to be attached to the ball so I can attach listeners to multiple balls. Is this possible? Thanks,

Comment: You've got some balls ?

Comment: ballsy! - consider having this nick :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery Draggable? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: try http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/ as example

Comment: yep, i've done them both.. they're good APIs, but I can't help but think about how i might implement my own...